# Apache Spark loads the entire partition into memory?

Tags: apache-spark

Apache Spark loads the entire  partition into memory or does it load gradually? Is there any reference (preferably official) about that?

If I have a large partition will be necessary to have the partition size in memory available?

Will loading data from the in-memory partition depend on the type of transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends of your file type, if it is `CSV/textFile` spark usually will load gradually even if you have multiple partitions and it depends of the size of the files. CSV does that because you cannot split by which data you need to read. `CSV/textFile` to get one row of data you need to scan the whole file.

If we are talking about `parquet` or `orc` files the format is naturally splittable. The data will never load the full files if you put some conditions during the read as `where` and `select` to choose the columns. That is why the recommended file size is around 1GB to optimise the spark time processing.

So if you are using parquet, each partition of spark should be able to be stored in memory while the process is going. Spark will try to store most partitions it can in the memory of the cluster during the transformations you are doing, if that cannot be fitted that will spill to the disk, reducing the execution time but ensure your execution to finish.

Comment: I didn't understand this "Data will never load the complete file unless you want to read the entire dataset.". If I do something like "select * from dataframe" will the entire partition be loaded into memory and if I do something like "select * from dataframe where condition", will spark only load filtered records into memory?

Comment: That goes based on the file type you are using. If you are loading Parquet, it will read the bottom of the file to see the data you need, if there is nothing on that file that match your query it will not load that file into the memory for transformation. But it will touch the file to find if the data is there or not. I will change my description there, I've found a little confusing as well.

Comment: Thanks! for your answer. I understand that whether it loads the entire partition into memory or not will depend on the file type (csv, parquet, orc, etc) and whether this type supports predicate push down. With push down predicate support like parquet has it will be possible to discard records before loading into memory. Not sure if being splitable will cause the partition to be loaded into memory in chunks smaller than its total size

Comment: That will be according to tuning, let's suppose that you are planning to load all ids between day `2022-01-01` and `2022-02-01`. If your data is not partitioned, that means all is in the same folder. And you run a filter on top of parquet files if that column is not sorted while you write, there is a really high chance you will load all records into memory and then filter it. Because ever single file will contain one date. If that is sorted in some ways, spark will check the meta of each parquet file and will just load the ones who contain the dates for filtering.

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim Assume a spark application with 100 cores/tasks. When I read a large single CSV file (300GB), how does spark creates 100 partitions? How does it instructs tasks to read from different positions/lines, so that it can be read parallelly?

Comment: That is why CSVs are a very inefficient file type. Spark will split by row count. Spark can store up 2Gb per partition based on Spark Java Serializer. If you have a 300GB file. That will be split on a minimum of 150 partitions, that will scan a batch of rows per time by the driver. Because it is impossible to point which byte in the file is the next row. So it will not read parallel on the first read, but it will process in parallel after it is parsed.

Comment: Hi everyone, I've made an experiment and in spark 3.2.1 and spark.files.maxPartitionBytes configured with the default (128MB), reading an cvs file with 5.2GB result in 41 partitions (5200/128). 

So I understood that the first read (read the csv and split to partitions) will be done by only one core in the driver (this first reading can't be done in parallel). So we can achieve 100 partitions with an csv with 300GB will be necessary to change spark.files.maxPartitionBytes to 3072 MB, but as Thiago says that the limit is 2 GB, changing this configuration to 2048 will give us 150 partitions.